# Updated excel chart in word document not getting reflected - apache poi

Tags: java, excel, charts, ms-word, apache-poi

I want to update charts in word document using Apache POI-3.17 in Java.
I am able to update underlying excel sheet related to chart using below code.
But when I open the word document charts are not getting reflected as per updated values
When I click on chart and do "Edit Data" at that time chart is reflected.
Code is as below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.RelationPart; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;




public class SherlockApp {



public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fileName = "D:\\Circular Economy Report Template.docx";

    try (XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileName)))) {

        // output the same as 8.1
        List<XWPFParagraph> list = doc.getParagraphs();
        for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : list) {
            // System.out.println(paragraph.getText());
        }

        for (POIXMLDocumentPart part : doc.getRelations()) {
            if (!StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getPackagePart().getContentTypeDetails().getSubType(),
                    "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml")) {
                continue;
            }
            int i=1;
            
            for(RelationPart p : part.getRelationParts()) { 
                System.out.println("Test -> "+p.getDocumentPart());
                
                InputStream str = p.getDocumentPart().getPackagePart().getInputStream();
                
                XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(str);
                
                XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
                
                Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();

                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = itr.next();
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator(); // iterating over each column
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: // field that represents string cell type
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t\t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: // field that represents number cell type
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t\t");
                            break;
                        default:
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                }
                
                Cell cell = null;
                
                //update the details
                cell = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(2);
                cell.setCellValue(0.1);
                
                cell = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1);
                cell.setCellValue(0.9);
                
                System.out.println("Cell Value -> "+cell.getNumericCellValue());
                
                str.close();
                
                OutputStream oStr = p.getDocumentPart().getPackagePart().getOutputStream();
                book.write(oStr);
                book.close();
                
                
                
                //Update word document
                try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {
                    doc.write(out);
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    


}
}
```

Comment: [Apache POI 3.17 was released over 5 years ago](https://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.17), what happens when you upgrade to something at least from this decade?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer - I have update word document as well at the end

Comment: @Gagravarr - I can't I don't have any choice